# AWS Lambda Function Location

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I am going through the [AWS Create Lambda Function and Test it Manually (2.3) tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-dynamodb-create-function.html), and I used aws CLI, to create a function called ProcessDynamoDBStream. It is supposed to process DB events.

I called this function manually as stated in the tutorial and I had a success return output. I went to my Function section in my console to view the metrics of that function but I cannot find ProcessDynamoDBStream in my Functions.

What could be the problem?

Thank You

Comment: Please check the region in function and in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you followed the tutorial statement by statement, the function was created in North Virginia (us-east-1).

as stated here:

```
$ aws lambda create-function \
--region us-east-1 \
--function-name ProcessDynamoDBStream \
```

If this region was not present, the CLI deploys into your default region. You can check your default region by entering the following command (you can skip through without entering any value):

```
aws configure
```

output:

> AWS Access Key ID [****************]: 
>   AWS Secret Access Key [****************]:
>   Default region name [eu-central-1]:
>   Default output format [json]: